# Android application stops working when placed inside the play console (I put it as an internal test and closed test)

Tags: apk, sharedpreferences, translation, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I would like to ask for help to understand a bug!

I'm working on an app translation for languages = English, Portuguese, Spanish and Russian.

If I export the app via APK (by android studio), all the features work perfectly... But when exported via app bundle and placed inside the play console, the same stops working in some languages or completely changes all the writings being that the languages are being assembled by a string-array (it is inside the string folders of each language) and selected by an adapter that takes them from a spinner created with the 4 languages.

Does anyone have a similar error or some kind of resolution to my problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Observation: the save metod is in MainHub at the project, and I save the languages with a sharedPreferences, maybe it could be a problem?

I tried to change the type of test done on the play console and I also tried to remove dead code from the project to see if something was disturbing the operation, but I was not successful until then